# if some set of functions are not linear, how can their composition be a linear combination that solves a linear second order ODE?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

**What I am trying to arrive at is, If a function is the composition of some set of non-linear functions, how can that composition be linear?** Here is the example I has been working through.

Example 1: $y'' + y = 0$

$ sin(a+b) \neq sin(a) + sin(b) $     and     $ cos(a+b) \neq cos(a) + cos(b) $, they are not linear.

But it is obvious that any linear combination of $ y_1(x) = cos(x) $, $ y_2(x) = sin(x) $ is a solution to $y'' + y = 0$
because

if $y_1 = kcos(x)$ then $y_1'' = -kcos(x) $

and if $y_1 = csin(x)$ then $y_1'' = -csin(x) $

So I understand that a second order linear ODE has a complete solution that is a linear combination of the particular solutions. **What I do not grasp is why the particular solution itself does not have to be a linear function.**

In other words a function $G(x,y,y',y'')= 0$ is linear if G is linear, even if y and its derivatives are not linear functions of x?

This puzzles me because I do not know how the solution vectors of $G(x,y,y',y'')= 0$ would look in a vector space particularly because I thought that a vector space by definition must be linear and that a function $y = sinx $ cannot be represented with a vector.

Of course I know that I am wrong and there are holes in my  understanding.

What would the graph of solution vectors look like for $y'' + y' = 0$ and $ y = sin(x) $

And as a stretch, what is the analog of vectors for a non-linear space used to represent solutions to a non-linear differential equation?

Answer (score 5):

You're misunderstanding the meaning of "linear" here. The equation $y''+y=0$ is called linear because if you define $L(y)=y''+y$ then $L(c_1y_1+c_2y_2)=c_1L(y_1)+c_2L(y_2)$ for constants $c_1,c_2$ and functions $y_1,y_2$. In other words, $L$ is a linear operator; it acts on functions like a matrix acts on vectors. (Indeed functions *are* vectors in the sense that they live in vector spaces.) Nowhere here did we say that $y_1,y_2$ are themselves linear functions; if that were a requirement, this theory would be nearly useless, because linear functions satisfy only rather trivial ODEs.

Similarly, when we say a "linear combination" of solutions, we don't mean that the result is a linear function, we mean that we're combining the solutions together in a linear way, i.e. we are combining $y_1$ and $y_2$ into $c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ (with perhaps more terms just like these).

Comment: I see, thanks :)